# Как изменить include_blank в Contact Form 7 на мобильных телефонах?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Для десктопа `select` изменил `include_blank` вот таким способом:

```
function my_wpcf7_form_elements($html) {
function ov3rfly_replace_include_blank($name, $text, &$html) {
    $matches = false;
    preg_match('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $html, $matches);
    if ($matches) {
        $select = str_replace('<option value="">---</option>', '<option value="">' . $text . '</option>', $matches[0]);
        $html = preg_replace('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $select, $html);
    }
    add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'my_wpcf7_form_elements');
}
ov3rfly_replace_include_blank('menu-838', 'Выберите область', $html);
return $html;
```

}

А вот `multiple` не реагирует и на мобильных устройствах отображается дефолтное состояние:

`Объектов: 0`

Подскажите как заменить `include_blank` у мультиселекта и заменить `Объектов: 0` на значение `include_blank`, пока ничего подобного не нашел в гугле.

Первое, на что обратил внимание: у мульти селекта `<option value="">---</option>` отображается как `<option value>---</option>` поэтому и не происходит замена.

Так как в проекте `label` использоваться не будет, хотелось бы заменить значение "Объектов: 0" на значение "Область" или "Город", а вот уже когда выбраны варианты, то оставить "Объектов: 2-3".

[image: Поле "Область"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем информация для тех у кого будет подобный вопрос.

```
function my_wpcf7_form_elements($html) {
function ov3rfly_replace_include_blank($name, $text, &$html) {
$matches = false;
preg_match('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $html, $matches);
if ($matches) {
    $select = str_replace('<option value="">---</option>', '<option value="">' . $text . '</option>', $matches[0]);
    $html = preg_replace('/<select name="' . $name . '"[^>]*>(.*)<\/select>/iU', $select, $html);
}
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'my_wpcf7_form_elements');
}
ov3rfly_replace_include_blank('menu-838', 'Выберите область', $html);
return $html;
```

Выше приведенный хук делает замену для обычного поля `select`, так как ищет `<option value="">---</option>`.

Для `multiple` не нашел решение, но ещё в процессе.

А вот, что касается "Объектов: 0" как выяснилось, это никак не относится к `include_blank`. Это стандартное поведение мультиселекта на мобильных телефонах и изменить его можно средствами jQuery. На данный момент я воспользовался jQuery библиотекой для [Multiple Select](https://plugins.jquery.com/multiple-select/), [Demo](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/). В моем случае использовалась форма [The Placeholder](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#the-placeholder)